# How to replace STRING_AGG and CONCAT in MS SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
              ,(SELECT 
                  STRING_AGG(per.Descripcion,' , ') as Permisos
                  FROM [Jose].[dbo].[Usuarios] usua
                  left join dbo.permisos_has_usuarios perUsu
                  on perUsu.usuario_id = usua.id
                  left join dbo.Permisos per
                  on per.Id = perUsu.permiso_id
                  where usua.id = usu.[Id] ) as Permisos
              ,usu.[FechaNacimiento]
              ,usu.[HoraEntrada]
              ,usu.[HoraSalida]
          FROM [Jose].[dbo].[Usuarios] usu
          left join dbo.Cargos car
          on usu.Cargo = car.Id
```

I need renplaced the "STRING_AGG" to concat the sql server 2008

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Instead of trying to retrofit newer technologies to an older, unsupported platform... why not upgrade the platform?

Comment: As a side note, SQL Server 2008 has been *completely* supported for over 3 years now. Considering you want/need functionality like `STRING_AGG` you really should be looking to get that instance upgraded; it is *long* past time that your upgrade plans were finalised and implemented.